# how to get specific value cell index using rubyXL gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubyxl

I have a static header in my excel template and I want to find each column cell index using cell value.

Example:

Row1: cell1, cell2, cell3

I want to find the cell index which has a value [cell3].

Comment: Can you post what you have tried? Where you are having issues? What errors if any you are receiving?

Comment: i don't know how to find cell index using cell value. @engineersmnky

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to iterate over the cells and find the cell that equal some content

So as idea

```
def find_cell_by_content(worksheet, content)
  worksheet.each do |row|
    row.cells.each do |cell|
      return [cell.row, cell.column] if cell.value == content
    end
  end

  nil
end
```

This method will return row and column indices if such cell exists otherwise `nil`